# Session value not passing to next page

Tags: php, session, session-variables

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
include '../config.php';
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
$username = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];`enter code here`
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $password);
$password_md5 = md5($password);
$query = "select * from admin where `email` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password_md5'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn , $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result , MYSQLI_NUM); 
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION["id"] = $row['id'];
$_SESSION["role_id"] = $row['role_id'];
//$_SESSION["role"] = $row['role'];
$_SESSION["email"] = $row['email'];
//$_SESSION['admin'] = "admin";
header("Location: dashboard.php?page=dashboard");
}else{
$fmsg = "invalid username and password";
}
}
?>



<?php
$login_session = $_SESSION['id'];
$query = "select * from admin where id = '$login_session'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn , "$query");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result , MYSQLI_NUM);
?>
```

I am trying to login with session.I have login successfully but session value not passing to next page. I have try many time could any one help whats the issue..

Comment: Have you added `session_start();` in next page?

Comment: I have also started session on top of the next page I am getting this to next page when i var_dump(); ->array(4) { ["id"]=> NULL ["role_id"]=> NULL ["role"]=> NULL ["email"]=> NULL }

Comment: Please consider to use a more slow hashing algorithm. MD5 is not useful for password "hashing"!

Answer (score 1):

You have issue in getting data using `mysqli_fetch_array`. As you have specify `MYSQLI_NUM` it will return **Numeric array**. You want **Associative array** Because further you are using its key

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result , MYSQLI_ASSOC);  //<----change here
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION["id"] = $row['id'];
$_SESSION["role_id"] = $row['role_id'];
//$_SESSION["role"] = $row['role'];
$_SESSION["email"] = $row['email'];
//$_SESSION['admin'] = "admin";
header("Location: dashboard.php?page=dashboard");
}else{
$fmsg = "invalid username and password";
}
```